# How would I retrieve links of every page, and through those links, I want to retrieve links of the products

Tags: python

```
next_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='ge-49M']")
for i in next_btn:
    driver.get(i)
    lnks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='_2UzuFa']")
    for z in lnks:
        href_new.append(z.get_attribute('href'))
```

Here I am trying to retrieve all the links present in every page like(1,2,3,4,5) and from these links I want to retrieve the links of the products.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-118-b4d6c76aecdf> in <module>
      1 next_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='ge-49M']")
----> 2 for i in next_btn:
      3     driver.get(i)
      4     lnks = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='_2UzuFa']")
      5     for z in lnks:

TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

But it's throwing this error.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has two functions for locating via xpath.

- `find_element_by_xpath` which returns the first matching element or raises an exception if no matching elements are found.
- `find_elements_by_xpath` (note the 's' on the end of element**s**) which returns a list containing every matching element; which will be empty in the case of no matching elements.

You're using the former function which returns a WebElement. WebElements aren't iterable so iterating over them is a TypeError. You should switch to the later function `find_elements_by_xpath`. This will return a list of elements you can iterate over.